# Is okhttp3.EventListener reliable regarding time-measurements - how do you measure time correctly

Tags: android, http, kotlin, https, okhttp

I did a very interesting experience using EventListener with okhttp3 in an Android mobile project,
where I want to do performance measurements regarding upload and download transfer rate by sending a http POST request without having the big time for SSL Handshake included

I therefor installed a derived class of EventListener which is overriding all http lifecycle-methods and measure the time by using System.currentTimeMillis()
I'm measuring a roundtrip by sending 65kBytes in the body of the post request and the backend is returning 65kBytes in the response

Following typical lifecycle sequences are invoked:

```
*** callStart
*** resetMetricData
*** secureConnectStart
*** secureConnectEnd
*** connectionAcquired
*** requestHeadersStart
*** requestHeadersEnd
*** requestBodyStart
*** requestBodyEnd, requestBodyStartingTime: 1626892169366 , requestBodyTimeMS: 4 , requestBodyPayload: 65850
*** responseHeadersStart
*** responseBodyStart
*** responseBodyEnd responseBodyStartingTime: 1626892169564 , responseBodyTimeMS: 415 , responseBodyPayload: 65862
```

I'm taking the time in the requestBodyStart method, and 4 ms later the requestBodyEnd method is invoked showing that 65'850 Bytes have ben sent.
I somehow do not trust this data, due similar case in the opposite way is showing 415 ms download the response body of 65'862 Bytes

If I show you the logs which containing the log-timestamp you can see, that the callbacks are really invoked on that time, ok there is a time of 5 ms between
requestBodyStart and RequestBody end, but i still have the feeling this is not correct and in reality takes much longer than just 4 ms.

Here are the Logs:

```
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,084] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** callStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,085] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** resetMetricData
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,154] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** secureConnectStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,340] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** secureConnectEnd
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,346] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** connectionAcquired
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,359] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** requestHeadersStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,363] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** requestHeadersEnd
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,365] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** requestBodyStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,370] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** requestBodyEnd, requestBodyStartingTime: 1626892169366 , requestBodyTimeMS: 4 , requestBodyPayload: 65850
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,373] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** responseHeadersStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,559] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** responseBodyStart
[2021-07-21 20:29:29,979] RoundTripMeasurementService$RoundTripEventListener : [20521::pool-2-thread-1] INFO [RoundTrip] *** responseBodyEnd responseBodyStartingTime: 1626892169564 , responseBodyTimeMS: 415 , responseBodyPayload: 65862
```

Here is the class implementing the EventListener:

```
inner class RoundTripEventListener : EventListener(), Loggable {
        @Volatile var sslHandshakeStartTimestamp: Long? = null
        @Volatile var requestBodyStartingTime: Long? = null
        @Volatile var responseBodyStartingTime: Long? = null

        fun resetMetricData() {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** resetMetricData")
            sslHandshakeStartTimestamp = null
            requestBodyStartingTime = null
            responseBodyStartingTime = null
            sslHandshakeTimeMS = 0 // resetting last ssl timestamp
            requestBodyTimeMS = 0
            requestBodyPayload = 0
            responseBodyTimeMS = 0
            responseBodyPayload = 0
        }

        override fun callStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** callStart")
            resetMetricData()
        }

        override fun secureConnectStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** secureConnectStart")
            sslHandshakeStartTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }

        /**
         * this method will be invoked after a ssl-handshake has been finished
         */
        override fun secureConnectEnd(call: Call, handshake: Handshake?) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** secureConnectEnd")
            sslHandshakeStartTimestamp?.let {
                sslHandshakeTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis() - it
            }
        }


        override fun connectionAcquired(call: Call, connection: Connection) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** connectionAcquired")
        }

        override fun requestHeadersStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** requestHeadersStart")
        }

        override fun requestHeadersEnd(call: Call, request: Request) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** requestHeadersEnd")
        }

        override fun requestBodyStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** requestBodyStart")
            // we need to take this time after the ssl handshake has finished, due this callback is invoked to late and then only 3 ms
            // are recorded for the request time ,which is not correct
            requestBodyStartingTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        }

        override fun requestBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            requestBodyStartingTime?.let {
                requestBodyTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis() - it
            }
            requestBodyPayload = byteCount
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** requestBodyEnd, requestBodyStartingTime: $requestBodyStartingTime , requestBodyTimeMS: $requestBodyTimeMS , requestBodyPayload: $requestBodyPayload")
        }

        override fun responseHeadersStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** responseHeadersStart")
        }

        override fun responseBodyStart(call: Call) {
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** responseBodyStart")
            responseBodyStartingTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }

        override fun responseBodyEnd(call: Call, byteCount: Long) {
            responseBodyStartingTime?.let {
                responseBodyTimeMS = System.currentTimeMillis() - it
            }
            responseBodyPayload = byteCount
            logi("[RoundTrip] *** responseBodyEnd responseBodyStartingTime: $responseBodyStartingTime , responseBodyTimeMS: $responseBodyTimeMS , responseBodyPayload: $responseBodyPayload")
        }
    }
```

And here is the installation of the Listener:

```
 private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().eventListener(RoundTripEventListener()).build()
```

and here is the post

```
val request: Request = Request.Builder()
                                .url(url)
                                .post(body) // 65KBytes
                                .header(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, authorizationValue)
                                .build()


client.newCall(request).execute().use { // do some stuff with the Response}
```

So does anybody having some experience regarding using the EventLister with the okhttp3 client? The functionality of this class is great and it would make posible to measure pure up- and down-stream datatransfer without the time-consuming ssl handshake.

Thanks in advance for any proposal regarding that.
Luke

Answer (score 2):

The event methods are called when OkHttp begins and ends making syscalls to fill up the outbound TCP buffer. Your operating system will then deliver this data, which may be buffered again on various routers and gateways between your client and it's server.

The measurement you want is when the server receives the request body, but unfortunately OkHttp does not measure this. The best you can get is the round trip time between finishing the request and receiving the response.